# remove on focus background color of ngbDropDown that uses btn-outline-dark

Tags: angular

What I want to achieve is the following display (saw in another app), which I am not close I suppose:

[image: Desired Output]

In my attempt to re-create, I get the following:

[image: My control]

Mine have no borders however the main headache I am having is that when it is focused, it displays a dark background color as the below:

[image]

Update:

How do I get rid of the background color when it is clicked or opening up?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uygtyz)

```
<form action="" role="form">


          <div class="form-group">

              <!-- Ask the user which role they are -->
              <div ngbDropdown>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="dropDownRole" ngbDropdownToggle style="width: 100%;">
                      <span> Dude </span>
                </button>
                <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropDownRole" style="width:100%;">
                  <button class="dropdown-item" style="width:100%">
                    Elim
                  </button>

                  <button class="dropdown-item" style="width:100%">
                      Elim 2
                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since you still couldn't find the issue i checked it and found a solution. Add this to your stylesheet and make sure this is loaded **after** the bootstrap css

```
.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .show>.btn-outline-dark.dropdown-toggle:focus,
.btn-outline-dark:hover, .btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .show > .btn-outline-dark.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #343a40;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

When you use the chrome inspector tools you can toggle the **:hov** tab en select different states of the element (see screenshot)

Then you can see the css that is added and the styles that are used when an element is focused for example.

in this case a box-shadow is added to the button when focussed. you can disable this by setting the box-shadow to none.

```
.btn-outline-dark:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of chrome inspector]

Comment: thanks for the new tip. I tried your fix. It didn't have any effect but I did try with :hover and it changes but unfriendly. btn-outline-dark {...styles } seem to have effect as well just the background color appears somewhere during the click/focus process. Thanks still.

Comment: on the plus side, I did get the shadow I wanted thanks to your tip...instead of none that is. But still the background color on click/hover appears.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

used like: `<button class='btn btn-primary shadow-none'>Example button</button`

Comment: That's make the fix for me